# Regular Expression in python - for loop/specific output

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Is there a way in which the function below can:

1. look through multiple files
2. print the actual email (John.doe@gmail.com) in **EACH** file

The `for` loop seems to be limited based on the number of pages in **ONE** file. How can it consider all 15 files, and print out the email?

Without the need for a list to match with (below):

```
emails = ["john@example.com", "python-list@python.org", "ug{}ly@email.com"]
```

I am using the below function to find emails throughout multiple files, but I am only getting results from one file.

```
for k in range(1,15):
    # open the pdf file
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("C:/my_path/file%s.pdf"%(k))

pattern = r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+\.\w+)\"?" 
        NumPages = object.getNumPages()

        
        for i in range(0, NumPages):
            PageObj = object.getPage(i)
            print("this is page " + str(i)) 
            Text = PageObj.extractText() 
            
        for subText in pattern.findall(Text):
            print(subText)
```

The output I am looking for:

```
file1: Jane.Doe@gmail.com
file2: John.doe@yahoo.com
.
.
.
etc
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What is the output you get?

Comment: If you are trying to loop over 15 files you need to set your range between `1, 16` or `0,15` because the range will return a list with the first number up to one before the last number in the range

Answer (score 0):

Because you get out of loop at declaring a pattern variable.

```
import re

pattern = re.complile(r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+\.\w+)\"?")
for k in range(1,15):
    # open the pdf file
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("C:/my_path/file%s.pdf"%(k))
 
    for i in range(object.getNumPages()):
        PageObj = object.getPage(i)
        print("this is page " + str(i)) 
        Text = PageObj.extractText() 

        for subText in re.findall(pattern, Text):
            print(subText)
```

By the way, I would change the pattern offhand to r""?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+?@\w+?.\w+?)"?"